# Check finiteness of ring map with SAGE

Tags: ring-theory, modules, ring-homomorphism, sagemath

(I asked this question in a SAGE-specialized forum --see [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/75240/finiteness-of-extension-of-rings/)--, but did not received an answer there sofar. I therefore decided to post the question also here.)

Let $R \rightarrow S$ be a ring map. I would like to check, using SAGE, if $S$ is finite as an $R$-module. In my case, $R$ and $S$ can be taken as polynomial rings in finitely many variables over a fixed finite field and the map $R \rightarrow S$ is given by some explicit polynomial functions. Is there some reasonable way to perform this?

I tried to implement this in some naive way, using the methods for ring extensions described [here](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/reference/rings/sage/rings/ring_extension.html):

```
 k = GF(17)
 R.<y> = k['y']
 S.<z> = R['z']
 L = S.over(R)
 L.is_finite_over()
```

This produces the following error (in cocalc, sage 10.1):

```
1598             pass<br/>
1599         b = (<RingExtension_generic?>b)._base<br/>
-> 1600     raise NotImplementedError<br/>
   1601 <br/>
1602 cpdef _is_finite_over(self, CommutativeRing base):<br/>
NotImplementedError:<br/>
```

I do not understand what causes the error. According to the description of "is_finite_over", the output in this minimal example should be simply "False". Note that when I replace $R$ by (say) $GF(5^2)$ and $S$ by $GF(5^4)$ then the output is "true", which is correct. Can it be that the function "is_finite_over" only works for field extensions, not general ring extensions (in contrast to what is said under the link)?

Whatever the reason for the described error is, how do I check finiteness of $S$ as an $R$-module with SAGE?

Comment: Your SAGE program is "polluted" : in order to have a clean presentation begin each line by 5 spaces (I have done it for you)

Comment: Thank you for correction!

Answer (score 0):

`NotImplementedError` means that it is not implemented. `is_finite_over` appears to be implemented in only very limited settings. Looking at the code, my guess is that it can't tell that `S` is finite over `R`; if it could, it would return `True`.

I don't know what answer you're expecting. What is the relationship between `y` and `z`?

Comment: Thank you for your observation. There is (an should be) no relation between y and z. In the minimal example above, I just wanted that R is a ring, which is not a field. So, here, R = k[y] and S = k[y,z] = R[z], so that neither R, nor S is a field. (N.B.: This is also more or less the setup in which I am interested in practice.)
The ideal answer I am expecting ($\rightarrow$ see the last sentense of my question) should tell me how I can check --given an SAGE-implementable homomorphism of two rings $R \rightarrow S$-- whether or not $S$ is finite as an $R$-module.

Comment: Since it's not implemented, there is no quick way to do it. If you know an algorithm, it might not be hard to implement it, at least for the sort of cases you are interested in.

Comment: It might very well be implemented indirectly. In fact, for modules over a ring, there is a function which is supposed to check finiteness. So, if there would be a way to interpret $S$ as an $R$-Module, then this function might help. But I could not find how to make $S$ an $R$-module. In principle, there might be also some other possible (standard?) solution, which I could not guess. My hope, when asking the question, was that sb encountered this (rather natural) problem already and knows a solution.